# Инструмент для форматирования HTML кода

Tags: html, javascript

Существуют ли JS скрипты для форматирования HTML кода(т.е. табуляции и все прочее)?
Пример:
Получаю через innerHTML такую разметку:

> `<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>`

А хочу сделать ее удобочитаемой(т.е. поставить отступы):

> ```
> <ul>
>   <li>1</li>
>   <li>2</li>
> </ul>
> ```

Да, забыл сказать, что сам HTML-код мне только вывести отформатированным надо.

Comment: Вопрос не очень понятен. Приведите пример.

Comment: а зачем js скриптом-то?

Comment: Может быть лучше использовать для этого возможности редактора/IDE в которых работаете?

Comment: 1.Пример.
Получаю через innerHTML такую разметку: <ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>
А хочу сделать ее удобочитаемой(т.е. поставить отступы):
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>

2.Зачем? Потому как из имеющихся средств есть только JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот несколько вариантов:

- [highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/ru/)
- [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)
- [JS Beautifier](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify)

Все три умеют форматировать и подсвечиватьь синтакс в HTML и JavaScript. Из последнего можно выдрать код, отвечающий непосредственно за форматирование HTML (файл beautify-html.js)

Comment: Спасибо. Для подсветки JS я уже использую CodeMirror. Я и не знал что в ней есть ф-я форматирования.